Why did Oswald leave Sofia to the Maronis?
In episode three of The Penguin, we see Oswald and Sofia working together; they try to find a distributor of their new street drug Bliss by striking a deal with the Triads.
During the episode, Oz works hard to prove his loyalty to Sofia and gain her trust. On one instance, he gives her the blackmail information he has on the Falcone underboss Johnny Viti and defends Sofia by strangling Viti when he mocks her for working with "the Penguin."
Oz even goes as far as having a seemingly heartfelt moment with Sofia and apologizing for "selling her out" to her father, which resulted in her being locked away in Arkham,

I’m f--ing sorry. You meant something to me, and I f--ed it up.

Not long after that, while outside the club, Oz and Sofia are jumped by Nadia Maroni and her gang, who are seemingly ready to kill them. However, right before they are executed, Victor shows up and saves Oz with his car. Before driving away, Victor asks,

What about Sofia?

And Oz responds,

F--k it, leave her

Oz and Vic then drive away, leaving Sofia in the hands of the Maronis.
Why would Oz do this after all his work to get in her good graces?

Didn't you see Oz completely submitting to Nadia once he had a gun to his head? Or Nadia telling Sophia that Oz killed her brother?

Yes, but I would assume he would try to talk his way out of it after all the work he did to gain her trust so he could get in on Bliss.

Oz fled the scene since Nadia revealed his role in Alberto Falcone's death, knowing Sofia would never forgive him for killing her brother Alberto.
Oz abandoned Sofia to the Maronis in episode 4 of The Penguin because his secret—that he had killed Alberto Falcone, Sofia's beloved brother—had come to light.
When Nadia confronts them, she reveals this devastating truth to Sofia. Alberto held special significance for Sofia, as he was the only person who remained loyal to her while everyone else, including her own family (and Oz), betrayed her. While Sofia was wrongfully imprisoned in Arkham Asylum after being framed as "The Hangman" killer, Alberto was her sole visitor and actively worked to secure her release.
Oz, knowing how close Sofia and Alberto were, realized that once she learned he had murdered her brother, any chance of partnership or trust between them was irreparably shattered.
